# Calculating orbits with varying laws of physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, simulations, computational-physics

The general way planets orbit stars in our universe is determined by the inverse square law and the three laws of motion.  Both the inverse square law and the three laws of motion are the reason that in our universe planets tend to orbit in eclipses.  I have run simulations on planetary orbits in which I could adjust the laws of physics in these simulations and found that using the same three laws of motion but adjusting the inverse square law changes the way planets orbit.  If the inverse linear law is used then planets in the simulation orbit in something like a flower shape while the inverse cube law produces spiral orbits.  The exponential decay laws also tend to produce flower shaped orbits.

I know how to simulate orbits using varying laws for Gravity but how can I mathematically calculate orbits using varying laws for Gravity?  Also how can I calculate the orbits of planets with varying laws of motion?  For instance if the first and second law of motion were changed how would I calculate planetary orbits in this case using any law of Gravity?  Also if Gravity depended partly on the speed that two masses have relative to each other how would this effect the way I would calculate planetary orbits?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. If you can simulate the orbit, you are already numerically solving the equations of motion, so what do you want to know here when you say *"how can I mathematically calculate orbits"* - you calculate them exactly as you do now, except that you try to find an analytical solution instead of a numerical one.

Comment: It may reassure you to know that for most potentials there are no analytical solutions that can describe the long term evolution of the system. The necessary criterion to find such solutions is called "integrability" and none but a handful of Hamiltonian systems are integrable. One can always find sufficiently precise local solutions that can be expressed by analytical functions (i.e. functions for which there is a locally convergent Taylor-series approximation) that are usually defined by integrals, but that's pretty much it. The long term dynamics of these systems is not predictable.

Comment: *...but adjusting the inverse square law...* needs (brief) explanation of what modifications were made.

Comment: Asking about changing the r-dependence of gravity is well-defined and answerable. But the bit about gravity depending on relative speed is not clear -- there are infinitely many ways one can imagine doing this. And changing the laws of motion is even more ambiguous -- what exactly are you replacing them with?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the laws of motion (presumably you mean Newton's Laws) means that you need to invent some new differential equations relating rates of changes of position and velocity to forces.  There's no guarantee that you will get any closed solutions or any non-chaotic paths.

More importantly, what checks will you impose on yourself to gain consistency and conserve energy, momentum, and angular momentum?  I believe that you will find that you can't conserve these without redefining those concepts themselves if you have new differential equations that are applicable to any general form of force.